# PreferenceActivity findPreference always return null

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

maybe this question asked million times. but i still got error after million tries.

I use this for setting pref

```
PreferenceFragment fragment;
try {
        getClass().getMethod("getFragmentManager");
        AddResourceApi11AndGreater();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { //Api < 11
        AddResourceApiLessThan11();
    }
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void AddResourceApiLessThan11()
{
    addPreferencesFromResource(prefs);
}

@TargetApi(11)
protected void AddResourceApi11AndGreater()
{
    PreferenceFragment fr = new PF();
    fragment = fr;
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fr).commit();
}


@TargetApi(11)
public static class PF extends PreferenceFragment
{       
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(AyarlarScreen.prefs); 
    }
}
```

and I still get null from findPreference and fragment.findPreference

(I m 4.0.4 android. so it uses Api11andGreter. so i save fragment ref, then use it to get pref. I can get preference if I use api11andlower manually)

Comment: The exact same problem here. Seems to fail on Android 4.0/4.1, work on 4.2 and up.